# How to check if object attribute is of type method-wrapper?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Some of the `callable()` attributes of an object are of type `<class 'method-wrapper'>`. Is it possible to check if a callable is of type `method-wrapper`?

For example `isinstance(object, methodwrapper)` or something like that?

---

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this: I have an object `a` of type `A` and I want to serialize it so I can send it over the wire. I also want to "serialize" the methods of that object. In particular, I want to send the source for each of the methods over the wire so it can be executed in some scope on the other side and injected into a re-creation of the `a` because the methods may have been changed or updated etc. So I go over all the methods, "serializing" them one at a time and then sending the json dictionary of `attribute_name -> attribute` over the wire. But I don't want to try to serialize methods of type `method-wrapper`. Now one way would just be to try and catch an exception when trying to serialize `method-wrappers` but I was wondering if there's another way.

Comment: In general, serializng executable code is not a straightforward task. In the case of just plain functions, there might be free variables that the code references, for instance. However, I'm guessing you're serializing the bytecode--the im_func, etc. In which case, you need to ensure that the interpreter on the other end is the same version, or it'll be unreliable. Can you somehow just serialize the source code from the file? Or recreate it from the disassembled code? Maybe this? https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

Comment: I am serializing the source of the function, not the actual code objects or VM code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you could do `str(type(a.foo)) == '<class 'method-wrapper'>` or something similar. If you have a guaranteed way to find a method that prints like that, you should also be able to do `methodwrapper = a.foo.__class__` which would then allow you to be able to do `isinstance(foo, methodwrapper)`. However, it's likely that there's a module which exposes these directly, but it's not in `builtins` that I can see. Not sure where else to look.

Edit:

```
>>> type(all.__call__)
<type 'method-wrapper'>
```

Comment: This is what I am using for now. Maybe I will switch to using the Edit method that you added. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is both possible and not recommended.

`'method-wrapper'` is an implementation type, and as such is specific to cPython.

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:49:51) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> object().__str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of object object at 0xb74dd4d0>
>>> type(object().__str__)
<type 'method-wrapper'>
```

Okay, but...

```
Python 2.7.3 (2.0.2+dfsg-4, Jun 28 2013, 11:25:07)
[PyPy 2.0.2 with GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``"that's however just engineering"
(fijal)''
>>>> object().__str__
<bound method object.__str__ of <object object at 0xb6bd29e8>>
>>>> type(object().__str__)
<type 'method'>
```

---

So, to stress how not-good of an idea this kind of type checking is, some sample code:

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def thing(self):
        pass
```

And me doing the following in cPython:

```
>>> isinstance(T(1).thing,type(object().__str__))
False
```

And now in pypy:

```
>>>> isinstance(T(1).thing,type(object().__str__))
True
```

So.  If you gave more details of what you're trying to accomplish, that might help.  Otherwise I leave you with the above cautionary tale.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realize it's not such a good idea. Please see the edit to my question above to see why I want to do what I want to do. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prehaps pick one at random and hope it is the base class of the implementation

```
isinstance(foo, dict.__len__.__class__)
```